# Zend custom Decorator not loading

Tags: php, zend-framework, decorator

I am getting the following error and do not understand why:

`Warning: Exception caught by form: Plugin by name 'TeamMember' was not found in the registry; used paths: Application_Decorator_: application/decorator/;decorator/
Zend_Form_Decorator_: Zend/Form/Decorator/`

I have worked from the documentation found here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.decorators.html

In the appliaction config file the namespace is defined `appnamespace = "Application"`

The decorator file was placed at **application/decorators/TeamMember.php**

The classname is `Application_Decorator_TeamMember`

During construction I have the following two lines:

```
$element->addPrefixPath('Application_Decorator', 'application/decorators/', 'decorator');
$element->addDecorator('TeamMember');
```

In the form viewScript I have the following:

```
echo $this->element->teamMember->renderTeamMember() . "<br />";
echo $this->element->teamMember->render() . "<br />";
```

The first line generates the error, the second will render the element with a label without adding the ":" to the end of the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turned out to be a "library" location was specified inside the application config file. That was used as the base directory. I had to either move the decorator file there or set the library location to the "application" directory, which is what I did.